# Goes into an IF but exits out to a ELSE

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Just started to write a script today but before I get into the main core of it when I run the below and select "M" for multiple - the IF statement goes to the "M" however, when it then pops up with a window to ask for a path and I on purpose close the window it errors and goes straight to the else statement...

How do I let the script end so that if I choose `$answer -eq "M"` then when I cancle out of the script then it closes there and then in that IF statement and not carry on to the ELSE statement.

I hope the above made sense - can't think of a better way to explain it..

ALSO...I am not happy with this statment of:

```
while("S","M" -notcontains $answer)
```

the problem is that if a person enters something else it just carrys on popping for the question. How do I error out if someone entered in an incorrect value and then ask the user "Please enter in "S" or "M"".

CODE:

```
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Backup Troubleshooting Script" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host ""

$answer = Read-Host "Do you want to check for multiple (M) servers or a single (S) server? Please enter "S" or "M""

while("S","M" -notcontains $answer)
{
    $answer = Read-Host "Do you want to check for multiple (M) servers or a single (S) server? Please enter "S" or "M""
}

If ($answer -eq "M")
{
    $serverlist = Read-Host "Please enter path to server list: "
    $computer = Get-Content -path $serverlist

        foreach ($computer1 in $computer)
        {
            Write-Host $computer1
            (Get-WmiObject -computerName $computer1 Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Alerter'").StopService()
            sleep 3
            (Get-WmiObject -computerName $computer1 Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Alerter'").StartService() 
            Write-Host `
        }

else
{
    Write-Host "You have chosen "S""
}
}
```

ERROR:

```
> Backup Troubleshooting Script
> 
> Read-Host : An error of type
> "System.Management.Automation.Host.PromptingException" has occurred.
> At
> C:\Users\gaachm5\AppData\Local\Temp\769b7304-5529-4f5c-aba7-2cd3dcc2cec9.ps1:15
> char:16
> +     $serverlist = Read-Host "Please enter path to server list: "
> +                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Read-Host], PromptingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.Host.PromptingException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ReadHostC
> ommand   Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path'
> because it is null. At
> C:\Users\gaachm5\AppData\Local\Temp\769b7304-5529-4f5c-aba7-2cd3dcc2cec9.ps1:16
> char:32
> +     $computer = Get-Content -path $serverlist
> +                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentComma
> nd   else : The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the  spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At
> C:\Users\gaachm5\AppData\Local\Temp\769b7304-5529-4f5c-aba7-2cd3dcc2cec9.ps1:27
> char:1
> + else
> + ~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (else:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>  
> 
>     Write-Host "You have chosen "S""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your curly braces are misplaced. The code should read:

```
            (Get-WmiObject -computerName $computer1 Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Alerter'").StartService() 
            Write-Host `
        }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "You have chosen "S""
}
```

Comment: @AthomSfere: No, I mean it was misplaced. In the OP's code, the braces are balanced.